# Android- How to replace DialogInterface click into Custom button click listener

Tags: kotlin, android-dialog

I'm passing click events for dialog from fragment class and performing in dialog as

```
fun showDialog(
title: CharSequence?,
message: CharSequence,
positiveText: CharSequence, positiveClick: (dialog: DialogInterface) -> Unit,
negativeText: CharSequence, negativeClick: () -> Unit,
) {
val alertDialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton(positiveText) { dialog, _ -> positiveClick.invoke(dialog) }

val alert = alertDialog.create()
alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
alert.show()
}
```

Now I'm going to create a new function for customised layout of dialog but I'm unable to click on buttons. I'm trying as

```
fun showDialog(
title: CharSequence?,
message: CharSequence,
positiveText: CharSequence, positiveClick: (dialog: DialogInterface) -> Unit,
negativeText: CharSequence, negativeClick: () -> Unit) {
val binding = DialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), null, false)

binding.positiveTextView.text = positiveText
binding.negativeTextView.text = negativeText
binding.messageTextView.text = message
binding.titleTextview.text = title

val alertDialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
alertDialog
    .setView(binding.root)

val alert = alertDialog.create()
alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
alert.show()

//Here positive click needs `View` but having `DialogInterface`
binding.positiveTextView.setOnClickListener { dialog -> positiveClick.invoke(dialog) }
//Its working fine now
binding.negativeTextView.setOnClickListener { _ ->
    negativeClick.invoke()
    alert.dismiss()
}
}
```

Here I'm unable to get click event as customised UI needs `View` but I'm having `DialogInterface`. Please help me to call clicks in customised dialog.

Comment: You're still passing in ``(dialog: DialogInterface) -> Unit`` for ``positiveClick``, isn't that why you need a ``DialogInterface``? Why not just do the same as ``negativeClick`` (which I'm assuming works fine?)

Comment: That’s also not working.

Comment: So if you change the listener to ``{ _ -> Log.d("Dialog", "clicked!") }`` and tap ``negativeTextView``, the message doesn't get logged?

Comment: It gets logged and if I try with existing functionality it popBackStack to previous fragment without closing the dialog.

Comment: Updated code with negative button and positive buttons events.\